# Find a time server for NTP to get the current time (EtherCard library)

Tags: time

There are lots of examples around how to connect with an NTP server, but I do not see how to find such an IP-address. From the examples I conclude I need to find it on for example [pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/nl), but I do not even see how to get IP-addresses out of there myself, let alone to let my Arduino do it. Of course I looked at the `How do I use pool.ntp.org` page, but it doesn't seem to say anything about finding IP-addresses.

**Questions**

> 1. Is it possible to let my Arduino find a working NTP server (using the EtherCard library), and if so, how?
> 2. All the examples I saw have an NTP server IP address hard coded, isn't that a bad practice and also a bad idea for a longer running project?

The code I currently find the easiest to understand is from the [Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=171941.0), and has an IP address hard coded.

I have an Arduino Nano ATmega328 with a ENC28j60 ethernet shield, and therefore use the `EtherCard` libray. I do know of existence of RTC devices but I would prefer NTP.

Comment: You need to perform a DNS lookup in order to convert the host name (e.g. "pool.ntp.org") into an IP address. Doesn't the EtherCard library have a facility for that?

Comment: @EdgarBonet That sounds logical, indeed EtherCard can do that, googling it it would be something like `if (!ether.dnsLookup(website)) { Serial.println("DNS failed"); } ether.printIp("Server: ", ether.hisip);` but I'm new to the ethernet connections so I need to find out how to get an ip address out of that to use later in the code...

Comment: I found an ip address with the code in the form of a string, but didn't manage to convert it to an array even with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227449/convert-ip-or-mac-address-from-string-to-byte-array-arduino-or-c so I'm leaving that for now. This question is solved I guess, although I am not sure of course if the ip is a correct one because I can't test it.

Comment: `ether.hisip` is not a string, it's an array of 4 bytes.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Oh indeed you are right! That solves my whole problem, thanks a lot! I was tricked into thinking it was a string by what `ether.hisip` printed to, but now I see that's why `ether.printIP` was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EtherCard` library offers a method called `ether.dnsLookup(host)` where you ask it to look up the IP address for you.

```
etherCard.dnsLookup("pool.ntp.org");
```

...only that might fail, so it returns a `false`:

```
if (!etherCard.dnsLookup("pool.ntp.org")) {
    // Error! Do something!
    return;
} // if
```

But if it works...

```
if (!etherCard.dnsLookup("pool.ntp.org")) {
    // Error! Do something!
    return;
} // if
// At this stage, dnsLookup() worked...

// Can now connect to IP adress in etherCard.hispip
```

Now: please note that `ntp.org` would prefer you to use a more precise locale than `pool.ntp.org`. If you're going to distribute your application worldwide, then that's fine. But I always use `au.pool.ntp.org` because I'm in the Australian region. There are [others](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/@) that you can/should use instead.

Comment: Thanks for writing Edgar's suggestion into an answer, the locale is a nice addition!